# HttpError 403 when requesting None returned "Insufficient Permission

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, io, google-drive-api, gmail-api

Uploading from  e-mail's attachments from Gmail to Google Drive:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import pickle
import os.path
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request

import io
import base64
from googleapiclient.http import MediaIoBaseUpload
from time import sleep


q='has:attachment'
maxResults=int(input("Please specify the number of emails with attachments that you would like to see:"))

#for drive api---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.pickle.

creds = None
# The file token.pickle stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
# created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
# time.
if os.path.exists('token_drive.pickle'):
          with open('token_drive.pickle', 'rb') as token_drive:
               creds = pickle.load(token_drive)
# If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
if not creds or not creds.valid:
   if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
           creds.refresh(Request())
   else:
      flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
     Credentials_drive.json', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly')
      creds1 = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
      # Save the credentials for the next run
      with open('token_drive.pickle', 'wb') as token_drive:
           pickle.dump(creds, token_drive)

   drive_service= build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds1)


sleep(5)
    

# for gmail api---------------------------------------------------------------------------------   
# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.pickle.



creds = None
# The file token.pickle stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
# created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
# time.

if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
            with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
                 creds = pickle.load(token)
        
# If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
if not creds or not creds.valid:
    if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
               creds.refresh(Request())
    else:
       flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
      'Credentials.json', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly')
       creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
       # Save the credentials for the next run
       with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
             pickle.dump(creds, token)
            
    service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=creds)




# Call the Gmail API
results = service.users().labels().list(userId='me').execute()

#Get Messages

results = service.users().messages().list(userId='me',q=q, maxResults=maxResults ,labelIds=['INBOX']).execute()
messages = results.get('messages', [])


def create_folder_in_drive(service,folder_name,parent_folder=[]):
    file_metadata ={
        
        'name':    folder_name,
        'parents': parent_folder,
        'mimeType':'application/vnd.google-apps.folder' 
        
        }      



for  message in messages:
            msg = service.users().messages().get(userId='me',metadataHeaders=['parts'], id=message['id']).execute()
            messageID=msg['threadId']
            messageSubject='(No Subject)({0})'.format(messageID)
            msgdetail=msg.get('payload')
          
            for item in msgdetail['headers']:
                if item['name']=='Subject':
                   if item['value']:
                       messageSubject='{0} ({1})'.format(item['value'],messageID)
                   else:
                       messageSubject='(No Subject)({0})'.format(messageID)
            print("messagesubject:" ,  messageSubject    )
            
            
            #create drive folder
            folder_id=create_folder_in_drive(drive_service,messageSubject)
            
            if 'parts' in msgdetail:
                
                for msgPayload in msgdetail['parts']:
                    mime_type=msgPayload['mimeType'] 
                    file_name=msgPayload['filename']
                    body=msgPayload['body']
                    print(body)
                    if 'attachmentId' in body:
                        attachment_id=body['attachmentId']
                        response=service.users().messages().attachments().get(
                            userId='me',
                            messageId=msg['id'],
                            id=attachment_id
                        ).execute()
                        
                        file_data=base64.urlsafe_b64decode(
                             response.get('data').encode('UTF-8'))
                                            
                        fh=io.BytesIO(file_data)
                        
                        file_metadata= {
                          'name':file_name,
                          'parents':[folder_id]
                            
                        }
                        
                        media_body=MediaIoBaseUpload(fh,mimetype=mime_type,chunksize=1024*1024,resumable=True)
                        
                        file=drive_service.files().create(
                          body=  file_metadata,
                          media_body=media_body,
                          fields='id'
                            
                            ).execute()
```

Hello friends, if I delete the token.pickle and token_drive.pickle files (these files are created separately from google cloud) in the file directory and run the code:

"ResumableUploadError: <HttpError 403 when requesting None returned "Insufficient Permission: Request had insufficient authentication scopes.". Details: "[{'domain': 'global', 'reason': 'insufficientPermissions', 'message': 'Insufficient Permission: Request had insufficient authentication scopes.'}]"> error", when I run the code without deleting the pickle files, I get the error which is "NameError: name 'service' is not defined."

It seems like a problem with authentication of Gmail and Drive at the same time because   media_body and file_metadata return a value, but I couldn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#for gmail and drive api------------------------------------------------------------

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.pickle.
SCOPES=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata']


creds = None
# The file token.pickle stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
# created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
# time.

if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
    with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
         creds = pickle.load(token)

# If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
if not creds or not creds.valid:
    if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
       creds.refresh(Request())
    else:
       flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
      'Credentials.json', SCOPES)
       creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
       # Save the credentials for the next run
       with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
             pickle.dump(creds, token)
    
service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=creds)
drive_service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)
```